# How do I download a chef data bag

Tags: chef-infra, knife, databags

I am trying to download an entire data bag item with all the json files contained within it from my chef server but the knife download command does not seem to work. I have tried:
`knife download my_databag_name`
but this returns nothing in the command line and the data bag file cannot be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `knife download data_bags/bagname` or (if you don't need it as separate files) `knife search bagname *:*`.